# A linear map from $\mathbb {R^2}$ to $\mathbb {R^2}$ maps unit circle to unit circle then what can you say about the linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> A linear map from $\mathbb {R^2}$ to $\mathbb {R^2}$ maps unit circle to unit circle then what can you say about the linear map?

**My Approach:** Let $T$ be the linear map . here $T(0,0)=(0,0)$

Suppose $x$ is a nonzero element of $\mathbb {R^2}$ then consider $\frac{x}{||x||}$.

Now, $T(x)=T(||x||\frac{x}{||x||})=||x||T(\frac{x}{||x||})$

So, $||T(x)||=||x||\cdot||T(\frac{x}{||x||})||$

Now, $T$ maps unit circle to unit circle hence $||T(\frac{x}{||x||})||=1$  , since $||\frac{x}{||x||}||=1$

So, $||T(x)||=||x||$ for all $x \in \mathbb {R^2}$

So, $T$ is an isometry. Using the following formula we can also prove that $T$ preserves angle since $T$ preserves inner product.

$<v|w>=\frac{1}{4}||v+w||^2-\frac{1}{4}||v-w||^2$

and   cos $\theta=\frac{<v,w>}{||v||\cdot||w||}$,

Now, angle between $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, So angle between their images ,must be $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I think $T$ must be one of rotation or reflection. But I can't prove it.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proven that $T$ must be an isometry. In particular, $T$ is invertible and its inverse is its adjoint. Indeed, let $A$ the matrix representation of $T$, we must have:

$$(x,y)=(Ax,Ay)=(A^TAx,y)$$

The first equality being the scalar product conversation by isometries.

If we take $x,y$ in all possible combinations of the canonical basis $e_1,e_2$, then we have that $A^TA=Id$. This relation implies, by some algebra using that $det(A)= \pm 1$ and the general inverse formula for 2x2 matrices that

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \text{ or } A = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & -\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$$

which are exactly rotation (around the origin) and/or reflections (from a plane going through the origin).

Answer (score 0):

You can ask something more. It is sufficient to require just $T$ is a multiplicative map and that the unit circle is mapped to itself.

Indeed, if you follow your reasoning, then you just used that $T(\lambda x)=\lambda T(x)$.

At a certain point you obtain that $T$ is an isometry. A classical theorem says that isometries of $\mathbb R^2$ are just affine maps. Since in your case $T(0)=0$, then your isometry is a linear map.

Now, the only linear maps which are isometries are rotations or reflections whose axis is passing through $O$ (this is a classical Theorem due to Charles, 1831).

If you need more details, please tell me and I can try to answer you :).

Comment: I think the goal of this question is exactly to prove that linear isometries of the plane are rotations and reflections and not to use a theorem for that.